# ItemMeta - command and listener

Tags: java, bukkit

How can I use itemmeta in another class?

```
public class Kart implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("kart")) {
            if (p.hasPermission("teamenders.komut.kart")) {

                ItemStack kart = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER);
                ItemMeta kartM = kart.getItemMeta();
                ArrayList<String> tt = new ArrayList<String>();
                kartM.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Yetki Karti");
                tt.add(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Giris Yetkisi");
                kartM.setLore(tt);
                kart.setItemMeta(kartM);
                p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(kart));

            } else {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Yetersiz Yetki!!!!!");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My 2nd class:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    if (e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
        if (p.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.PAPER && p.getItemInHand().hasItemMeta()) {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Yetkiyi aldin.");
        }
    }
}
```

I want use first class `itemmeta` in 2nd class `"p.getItemInHand"`

Comment: Do you know how object oriented programming works?

Answer (score 0):

Store it using an ArrayList outside of your Kart class, then retrieve the data in your EventHandler.

Comment: Can you give an example for my plugin? I did not understand well.

Answer (score 0):

In your first class, create a global variable (outside any function) and store the value of `kart.getItemMeta()`.

Still in your first class, create a function that returns this variable.

In your second class, create another global variable `Kart kart` and create a function `public *nameOfYourClass*(Kart kart){this.kart = kart}`. You should then be able to do `kart.*functionOfFirstStep*`.

Please tell me if I wasn't clear enough.